# Не запускается батника c s3cmd командой по расписанию. В ручную работает

Tags: python, windows

Настраиваю бэкап по расписанию. Есть батник backup.bat, в нем строка

```
C:\Python27\python C:\Backup\s3cmd get s3.........
```

Если запускаю его вручную - всё работает, если добавляю в планировщик - не запускается. Перепробовал уже все варианты галочек в планировщике. Как заставить его запускаться по расписанию?

Comment: Вы хотите запускать .bat по расписанию? А при чем тут python?

Comment: Далее подставляются разные переменные еще с помощью bat-инструкций. Скрипт  s3cmd - это питоновская тулза для резервного копирования в s3

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в самом скрипте s3cmd, который использовал переменные окружения windows. Я их задал явно в вызывающем батнике и всё заработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В консоли или из пакетного файла *.bat можно выполнить команду at. Вот пример:

```
at 08:00 cmd /c "taskkill /f /im explorer.exe"
```

Данная команда вырубит процесс explorer.exe в 8:00
Думаю смысл понятен. Для создания бекапа вместо taskkill используейте например xcopy или robocopy. Думаю идея ясна.

Comment: Чего-то не понятно. Мне нужно запускать конкретную утилиту, написанную на питоне, по расписанию и не будучи при этом залогиненным. xcopy не положит в амазон файл.